# Google API Quickstart

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I've run into the problem with Google API quickstart. I couldn't verify the token because it says that the token format is invalid. The strangest part was that I was able to make it run a few months ago on another project, but now I can't do anything.

My quickstart.php look as:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

if (empty($values)) {
    print "No data found.\n";
} else {
    print "Name, Major:\n";
    foreach ($values as $row) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to enter the token it returns following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid token format in ..\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php:469
Stack trace:
#0 ..\quickstart.php(45): Google_Client->setAccessToken()
#1 ..\quickstart.php(63): getClient()
#2 {main}
  thrown in ..\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 469
```

I've tried to append for `$authCode` token manually, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to reauthorize your application delete the token.json file and run it again.

Comment: Yes, it haven't token.json currently

Comment: To be sure I made new project in google api with new credentials, but still says same error

Answer (score 0):

So it literally was my mistake, our front engine changed the link "a bit" so it wasn't be able to be verified. As I've changed to a random domain and copied the token everything worked well.